# WWW request does not connect using webgl platform

Tags: unity, html5

I use request like code below:

```
string url = "http://localhost:51820/Home/login/" + end+"/";
        WWW www2 = new WWW(url);
        StartCoroutine(waitForLogin(www2));
```

It works fine in the editor but the html build shows a connection problem. message of www error is only "unknown error"

Comment: use a local webserver. I recommend **NOT** using something giant like apache or iis. Instead use something simple like [the ones mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look into your browsers error console, you will likely notice an error message like this:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:51820/Home/login/

For security reasons, web browsers do not allow javascript applications to send http requests to localhost when they aren't also loaded via localhost. Note that loading a html document via the `file:///` pseudo-protocol is **not** considered the same as loading from `http://localhost`.

What you can do as a workaround is put the game into the document directory of your local webserver and also load it via an URL like `http://localhost:51820/yourgame/index.html`.

Comment: I thought this was a cross-origin problem, but I wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: now my game is my localhost and server is on a vps server but still there is the problem. as I read problem can be caused when request has not the same origin of server. how can I fix it?

Comment: @virtouso You might have to enable [cross-origin resource sharing](https://enable-cors.org/) on the server. How to do that depends on the webserver software. But the website I linked to has lots of explanations for different webservers.

Comment: @Philipp its a windows server 2016. I'm searching on internet but ill be glad to say if you know it

Comment: @Philipp I just added headers In https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html in iis10 HTTP response Header. but it still doesn't work