# www.texture and www.LoadImageIntoTexture both just show red question mark

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to use [this code I found in the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html) to display a remote image on a plane.  However, no matter what URL I try, it only displays a red question mark.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class KnowledgeWall_WeatherMap : MonoBehaviour {

    // The source image
    //public string url = "https://radar.weather.gov/Conus/Loop/northrockies_loop.gif";

    public string url = "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg";

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
        using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
        {
            yield return www;
            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried the [code here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html), which is slightly different. It gave the same result.
Unfortunately this project is Unity 5.3.6.  **How can I fix this so Unity 5 displays the remote image?**

Comment: Does this problem occur only in the HTML5 build? Then it might be a duplicate of [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/152298/21890).

Comment: No, this is a Windows build, but it's happening in the editor Game view.

Comment: Note that gif files are unsupported, only jpg and png. Just a heads up in case you plan on trying to go back to your commented out code at some point.

Comment: Also, sanity check: is the URL set to something else in the inspector? Perhaps it is still pointing to the gif?

Comment: The inspector points to the png.  Too bad about the gif, that was the only reason I needed this.  Thanks.